# Using the Bolzano–Cauchy Theorem, prove that the equation $x^2+x−\cos x=0$ has at least one solution in the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Using the Bolzano–Cauchy Theorem, prove that the equation $x^2+x−\cos x=0$ has at least one solution in the interval [0,1].

Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function if the signs of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are different (for example, $f(a) > 0, f(b) < 0$).
Then there is a point $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

- For $x=0 \implies 0^2+0−\cos 0=-1$
- For $x=1 \implies 1^2+1−\cos 1 = 2 - \cos 1 \approx 2 - 0.54\ldots \approx 1.46\ldots$

Since $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$ we have $f(a) f(b) < 0$, so by the theorem there is a $c \in [a ,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

This is enough? seems very simple, am i missing something? Because the theorem doesn't say how to find the root, it just guarantees that there is at least one.

Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question. Please do not add tags to the title.

Comment: It must be said that $f(x)=x^2+x-\cos(x)$ is continuous, but the rest is perfect